# counting indicator respect of 2 groups

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a group and persons in each group. and an indicator. How to count indicator per each group for each person element?

```
     group  person   ind
       1       1      1
       1       1      1
       1       2      1
       2       1      0
       2       2      1
       2       2      1
```

output
   so in the first group 2 persons have 1 in ind, and second group one person so

```
      group  person   ind.   count  
       1       1      1        2
       1       1      1        2
       1       2      1        2
       2       1      0       1
       2       2      1        1
       2       2      1        1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sum a variable by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660124/how-to-sum-a-variable-by-group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could do:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(
    count = n_distinct(person[ind == 1])
  )
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   group [2]
  group person   ind count
  <int>  <int> <int> <int>
1     1      1     1     2
2     1      1     1     2
3     1      2     1     2
4     2      1     0     1
5     2      2     1     1
6     2      2     1     1
```

Or in `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, count := uniqueN(person[ind == 1]), by = group]
```

Answer (score 1):

An option using `base R`

```
df1$count <-  with(df1, ave(ind* person, group, FUN = 
          function(x) length(unique(x[x!=0]))))
df1$count
#[1] 2 2 2 1 1 1
```